# Estimation with Windows Function BIGQUERY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This is my sample data.

| id | st | event | et | state_event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 00:11:00 | 005 | null | 1 |
| 1 | 00:12:00 | 001 | 00:15:30 | null |
| 1 | 00:13:00 | 005 | null | 2 |
| 1 | 00:14:00 | 005 | null | 3 |
| 1 | 00:15:00 | 005 | null | 2 |

st = start_time,

et = end_time,

The '001' event is an event with a time range.

The '005' event is an event that causes a state change.

I want to divide the '001' event record according to the time when the '005' event occurred as follows. And I want to estimate the state column.

(I want this output)

| id | st | event | et | state_event | state_estimation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 00:11:00 | 005 | null | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 00:12:00 | 001 | 00:13:00 | null | 1 |
| 1 | 00:13:00 | 005 | null | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 00:13:00 | 001 | 00:14:00 | null | 2 |
| 1 | 00:14:00 | 005 | null | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 00:14:00 | 001 | 00:15:00 | null | 3 |
| 1 | 00:15:00 | 005 | null | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 00:15:00 | 001 | 00:15:30 | null | 2 |

I tried the code that predicts the state. The query below seems to work fine.

```
WITH test AS (
            SELECT '1' AS id, '00:11:00' AS st, "005" AS event, NULL       AS et, "unfold" AS state_event
  UNION ALL SELECT '1' AS id, '00:12:00' AS st, "001" AS event, '00:15:30' AS et, NULL AS state_event
  UNION ALL SELECT '1' AS id, '00:13:00' AS st, "005" AS event, NULL       AS et, "flex" AS state_event
  UNION ALL SELECT '1' AS id, '00:14:00' AS st, "005" AS event, NULL       AS et, "fold" AS state_event
  UNION ALL SELECT '1' AS id, '00:15:00' AS st, "005" AS event, NULL       AS et, "flex" AS state_event
)
SELECT id, st, event, et, state_event,
LAST_VALUE(state_event IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY st ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS state_estimation,
FROM test
ORDER BY id, st
;
```

However, it is difficult to divide 001 event with 005 events.

Could you please help?

Comment: Is it right assumption for input data, that every ID contains few 005 events and the only one 001 event?

Comment: In real data,  few 005 events and few 001 events are mixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below query:

```sql
WITH test AS (
            SELECT '1' AS id, '00:11:00' AS st, "005" AS event, NULL       AS et, "unfold" AS state_event
  UNION ALL SELECT '1' AS id, '00:12:00' AS st, "001" AS event, '00:15:30' AS et, NULL AS state_event
  UNION ALL SELECT '1' AS id, '00:13:00' AS st, "005" AS event, NULL       AS et, "flex" AS state_event
  UNION ALL SELECT '1' AS id, '00:14:00' AS st, "005" AS event, NULL       AS et, "fold" AS state_event
  UNION ALL SELECT '1' AS id, '00:15:00' AS st, "005" AS event, NULL       AS et, "flex" AS state_event
),
splits AS (
  SELECT * FROM test WHERE event <> '001'
   UNION ALL
  SELECT id, 
         FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%T', TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(t)) st, event,
         FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%T', TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(LEAST(t + 60, et0))) et, state_event
    FROM test,
  UNNEST ([STRUCT(
           TIME_DIFF(SAFE.PARSE_TIME('%T', st), TIME '00:00:00', SECOND) AS st0,
           TIME_DIFF(SAFE.PARSE_TIME('%T', et), TIME '00:00:00', SECOND) AS et0
         )]),
  UNNEST (GENERATE_ARRAY(st0, et0, 60)) t
   WHERE event = '001'
)
SELECT *, LAST_VALUE(state_event IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY st) state_estimation
  FROM splits
 WHERE st <> IFNULL(et, '00:00:00')
 ORDER BY st, et;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is of great help to me.

Comment: But If I modify "'00:15:30' AS et" ->"'00:16:00' AS et" in test table, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @sproutee,  **doesn't work**  mean it prints out one additional record with **st** same as **et**?  If so, I've updated the query to ignore a corner case.

Comment: Yes, it prints out additional record. All events can hit in 1 second increments, so corner cases seem to occur.

Comment: I see, I think I've fixed that specific case. so kindly check the updated query and let me know if any other issues, I'll look at it at my free time.

Comment: Thanks for the modified query. It works with sample data. However, since the real data is in units of 1 second, a lot of corner cases occur. Now I am trying to test after changing (GENERATE_ARRAY(st0, et0, 60)) ->> (GENERATE_ARRAY(st0, et0, 1)).

Comment: Have you changed **TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(LEAST(t + 60, et0)) --> TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(LEAST(t + 1, et0))** as well ?

Comment: If **'00:13:00' AS st, "005" AS event -->  '00:13:12' AS st, "005" AS event** in test table, corner case occur.

Comment: seems state has changed at 00:13:12 by event "005".  would be more specific what corner case do you mean ?

Comment: Row id st event et state_event state_estimation 
// 1 
1
00:11:00
005
null
unfold
unfold
// 2 
1
00:12:00
001
00:13:00
null
unfold
// 3 
1
00:13:00
001
00:14:00
null
unfold
// 4 
1
00:13:11
005
null
flex
flex
// 5 
1
00:14:00
005
null
fold
fold
// 6 
1
00:14:00
001
00:15:00
null
fold
// 7 
1
00:15:00
005
null
flex
flex
// 8 
1
00:15:00
001
00:15:30
null
flex

Comment: 13:00~13:11 // 13:11~14:00 << It should be divided into two, but it is not.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I see what the problem is. but if the time interval of event 005 is not evenly divided in your table, it will be totally differen problem as it used to be, so it requires another approach.

Comment: I agree to consider another approach. Now I am trying to test with udf. **CREATE TEMP FUNCTION split_001_event(events ARRAY<STRUCT<event STRING, start_time TIMESTAMP, end_time TIMESTAMP, state_event STRING>>)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<event STRING, start_time TIMESTAMP, end_time TIMESTAMP, state_event STRING>>
LANGUAGE js AS """**